# In Ubuntu, how do I figure out which process is a network pig

Tags: networking, ubuntu

Using top it's easy to identify processes that are hogging memory and cpu, but ocasionally I see my computer's network activity spike, but I'm unable to determine which process is generating the activity.   Where is the right place to look for this information?

Comment: The same question can be found in a non-closed form at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can also take a look at "NetHogs": http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/. Little yet very handy utility. Especially if you want to find out which process is taking the bandwidth.

Comment: Aside of "nethogs", if you want to limit rate of any software that does not have such functionality built-in, then look at "trickle": http://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/.

Comment: Very good and simple program! I love these light software :)

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.10, nethogs is in the repo `sudo apt-get install nethogs`

Answer (score 12):

You can install several applications to monitor network traffic in real time. [NTOP](http://www.ntop.org/), [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/), [trafshow](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/trafshow.html), [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/).

I would go with NTOP or IPTRAF. But that's just a personal taste.

Also, with Linux's [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) you can use the **-p** flag to see how many connections is a process using.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/). In Ubuntu you can install it by typing in terminal: `sudo aptitude install iftop`. To use type: `sudo iftop -i eth0`, where eth0 is your network interface.

Comment: iftop is cool, but it shows where the traffic is going, not what process is doing it

Answer (score 3):

The package 'nmon' provides a comparable tool to top. The design's a bit different since the kernel doesn't provide excellent statistics via /proc.

```
Description: performance monitoring tool for Linux
 nmon is a systems administrator, tuner, benchmark tool.
 It can display the CPU, memory, network, disks (mini graphs or numbers),
```

There's also iftop:

```
Description: displays bandwidth usage information on an network interface
 iftop does for network usage what top(1) does for CPU usage. It listens to
 network traffic on a named interface and displays a table of current bandwidth
```

Comment: Tried this...install was odd as it wanted the 'admin' password.  Then it wouldnt run.

Comment: Ah, derp, I was thinking of nmon.

Answer (score 1):

lsof -i -n -P gives you for each connection the process and the endpoints...

Answer (score 0):

Small correction to Pablo Santa Cruz-

On linux: netstat -p gives the pid of the program running on the port. On BSD: netstat -p is used to specify the protocol.